# Debug Stream trace on functional code throws IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, stream

When I tried to debug the stream in the code below via Stream Trace in IntelliJ, the debugger can't evaluate the foreach because the error below is thrown. I have no idea what it's about, the code by itself runs fine.

Fully updated IntelliJ community edition, JUnit 5, Spring Boot, Maven, Java 11.

The error that happens during Stream Trace debugging only:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Type
>   com.progonkpa.file.FileService$GeneratedEvaluationClass$5 is not a
>   nest member of com.progonkpa.file.FileService: types are in different
>   packages

The code that contains the stream:

```
public class FileService {

    public void createDirs(File parentDir, String[] fileNames) {
        Stream.of(fileNames)
                .map(fileName -> new File(parentDir, fileName))
                .forEach(file -> {
                    if (file.mkdirs())
                        System.out.println("Created file: " + file);
                    else
                        System.err.println("Failed to create file: " + file);
                });
    }
}
```

The test that invokes the method above:

```
public class FileServiceTest {

    private FileService fileService = new FileService();

    @Test
    public void generateDirs_createsList() {
        File tmpDir = new File("/tmp");
        String[] dirNamesList = {"dir1", "dir2"};
        File createdDir1 = new File(tmpDir, dirNamesList[0]);
        File createdDir2 = new File(tmpDir, dirNamesList[1]);

        fileService.createDirs(tmpDir, dirNamesList);

        assertTrue(createdDir1.exists());
        assertTrue(createdDir2.exists());
        assertTrue(createdDir1.delete());
        assertTrue(createdDir2.delete());
        assertTrue(tmpDir.delete());
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.unknown.somefunction</groupId>
    <artifactId>joske</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--Data processing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>outlook-message-parser</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vatbub</groupId>
            <artifactId>mslinks</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Testing-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image: Stream Trace in IntelliJ Community Edition]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stream debugger apparently generates bytecode and defines classes on the fly to evaluate expressions.
Relevant source files are

[CompilingEvaluator.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/c306be2ddb811374c8bee59060d82abf2c971941/java/debugger/impl/src/com/intellij/debugger/ui/impl/watch/CompilingEvaluator.java)
[CompilingEvaluatorImpl.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/d431e257544b3e4c22f9de470f6b34b49985131e/java/debugger/impl/src/com/intellij/debugger/ui/impl/watch/CompilingEvaluatorImpl.java)

And there is a currently opened issue on YouTrack, with the exact same exception

```
Type some.Type$GeneratedEvaluationClass$1 is not a nest member of some.Type: types are in different packages
```

[IDEA-204665](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204665)

This manifests itself only on JDK versions greater than 10, and unfortunately you have

```
<java.version>11</java.version>
```

As the Issue suggest, it happens because

> JDK 11 has "Nest-based Access Control" feature
>   (https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/nestmates.html)

The [JEP 181](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181) says

> **Impact on Other Tools**
>
> Any tool that operates on classfiles, or which
>   generates or processes bytecodes is potentially impacted by these
>   changes. At a minimum such tools must tolerate the presence of the new
>   classfile attributes and allow for the change in bytecode rules. For
>   example:
>
> The javap classfile inspection tool, The Pack200 implementation, and
>   The ASM bytecode manipulation framework, which is also used internally
>   in the JDK.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait on a bug fix from Jetbrains. In the meantime, we can switch to Java 10 if it's really necessary and switch back to 11 when it's fixed.

Comment: @progonkpa if you use and debug  Stream(s) a lot, switch to JDK 10, would be a no-brainer for me. I Can't work without a debugger. Btw, I voted for the issue, you can do too if you register

Comment: @progonkpa usually they fix issues pretty fast. Must be a difficult one.